# pass double ArrayList in a bundle

Tags: android, arraylist, double, bundle

How can I pass Double ArrayList in a bundle?
[image]

`bundle.putIntegerArrayList()` exists but I cannot find `bundle.putDoubleArrayList()`

Comment: Is this android related? Please tag it properly (at least programming language tag, platform tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need use bundle. you can just put it in Intent directly. And because Array list implement Serializable you won't have any problems.

```
intent.putExtra("array", doubleArray);
```

If you need use Bundle then

```
bundle.putSerializable("array", doubleArray);
```

Comment: thanks man, but what should I put in the child intent? (I wrote ArrayList<Double> Pn_points=bundle.getSerializable("Pn_points"); but i get an error!)... what is the output? ArrayList<Double> or double[]?

Comment: What error you got? Its have to be ArrayList<Double>

Comment: Incompatible types error....but I cast it to ArrayList<Double> --> (ArrayList<Double> Pn_points=(ArrayList<Double>)bundle.getSerializable("Pn_points");) and the error has disappeared.

Comment: Ah year. I got it now. It's return ArrayList but your right you need to cast it to ArrayList. getSerializable return basic type

Comment: If answer is correct can you mark it as Correct answer?